# Can we put regex string in enviroment variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5

I have code in rails to check CORS from list of domain in env like this

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  domains = ""

  if ENV["DOMAIN_CORS"].present? && !ENV["DOMAIN_CORS"].empty?
    domains = ENV["DOMAIN_CORS"].split(",").map { |origin| origin.strip }
  end

  allow do
    origins domains
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options], credentials: true
  end
end
```

And i have env like this
DOMAIN_CORS = "https://example1.com, https://example2.com"

Above code work fine to check cors for those two domains, but if I want to allow all subdomain of **example.com** to work, after read somepost from here

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/30

I need to have regex check like

```
(.*?)\.example\.com
```

I set env to

```
DOMAIN_CORS = "https://example1.com, https://example2.com, (.*?)\.example\.com, /(.*?)\.example\.com/"
```

But all ways seem not work, so is there anyway that I can put regex string in env for this case ? . Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As you can see what they use in the linked rack-cors issue is of a `Regexp` class, and not a `String` as in your case.

I suggest concatenating 2 environment variables:

- STRING_DOMAIN_CORS="https://example1.com, https://example2.com"
- REGEXP_DOMAIN_CORS="(.*?).example.com"

and map them accordingly:

```
ENV['STRING_DOMAIN_CORS'].split(",").map { |origin| origin.strip } +
ENV['REGEXP_DOMAIN_CORS'].split(",").map { |origin| origin.strip }.map { |origin| Regexp.new(origin) }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your env variable string, enclose regular expression in between `//` so that we can retrieve and parse it accordingly:

```rb
DOMAINS_CORS = "https://example1.com, https://example2.com, /(.*?)\\.example\\.com/"
domains = DOMAIN_CORS.split(",").map(&:strip).map{ |x| x.start_with?("/") ? Regexp.new(x[1..-2]) : x }
 => ["https://example1.com", "https://example2.com", /(.*?)\.example\.com/]
 #=>  ^ string                ^ string                ^ regexp
```

Above parses and returns array of string and regexp objects which can be passed to `origins` like below

```rb
  allow do
    origins domains
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options], credentials: true
  end
```

Comment: Make sure if you construct regular expressions from a string like this that you anchor your regex with `\A` and `\Z`, because something like `/example\.com/` would match `example.com.somebadactor.net`.